# Why do I get a "Promise executor has already been invoked with non-undefined arguments" warning? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to make a stream / lazy list in Node.js (v12.20.1) using Promises. My essential idea with it is that a Stream could simply be a Promise that resolves to a value and another Stream. With that in mind I came up with this recursive definition:

```js
class Stream extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super((resolve, reject) =>
            executor(
                (value) =>
                    resolve({
                        head: value,
                        tail: new Stream(executor),
                    }),
                reject
            )
        );
    }

    map(f) {
        return this.then((cell) => {
            return {
                head: f(cell.head),
                tail: cell.tail.map(f),
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Now, this actually does everything I expect it to but prints out a couple of warning messages whenever a value is resolved. For example, using an event emitter as the source for the stream:

```js
 > const Stream = require('./stream')
undefined
 > const { EventEmitter } = require('events')
undefined
 > const emitter = new EventEmitter();
undefined
 > const stream = new Stream((yieldValue, reject) => emitter.once('foo', yieldValue));
undefined
 > stream.map(console.log);
Stream [Promise] { <pending> }
 > emitter.emit('foo', 1);
true
 > 1
(node:22271) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise executor has already been invoked with non-undefined arguments
    at /wd/stream.js:4:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new Stream (/wd/stream.js:3:9)
    at /wd/stream.js:8:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:22271) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22271) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
 > emitter.emit('foo', 2);
true
 > 2
(node:22271) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise executor has already been invoked with non-undefined arguments
    at /wd/stream.js:4:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new Stream (/wd/stream.js:3:9)
    at /wd/stream.js:8:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:22271) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

I really don't understand what is going wrong here. I don't get what the problem is with invoking the executor multiple times since it's just a function, and I certainly don't get what's causing the second warning since, as far as I can tell, none of the Promises are being rejected here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to design something that already exists? Node has a Stream class already. It isn't a subclass of promise, but it does have a promise api in which the async methods return promises.

Comment: @danh Yeah I'm making this more for learnings than anything else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this.then()` constructs a new promise, following the contract of the `Promise` constructor which you have subclassed. To do so, it calls your `Stream` constructor with an executor that will use the passed resolver functions to resolve the new promise with the results from the `then` callbacks. This executor is expected to be called back only once - however your `Stream` does call it multiple times, once immediately and then during the `resolve` call.

Of the various promises constructed by your `stream.map(console.log);` call that never are handled anywhere, some appear to get rejected - rightfully if you ask me.

A Stream may *consist* of recursively chained promises<sup>1</sup>, but a stream *is* not a `Promise`. Do not use subclassing!

<sub>1: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31814732/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414193/1048572) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21905355/1048572)) for examples. Notice that this linked-list like concept has been superseded by [asynchronous iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) ([blog post](https://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html)) now which have a stateful `next()` method. You will also want to have a look at [What is the difference between async generators and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48512319/1048572).</sub>